# jQuery Plugin - update element after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i pass a new value to public method `updateText` to update the content inside the element?

Currently when i pass a new string to `updateText` method upon clicking the button i get only method name as an argument and not the passed string.

```js
(function ($) {

    var pluginName = 'testPlugin';
    var defaults = {
        elementText: 'Default element text',
        elementColor: '#fff'
    };

    function Test (element, options) {
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.$element = $(element);

        if (this[options]) {
            return this[options].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof options === 'object' || !options) {
            return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }

    // Main methods
    Test.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            this.$element.text(this.options.elementText);
            this.$element.css('color', this.options.elementColor);
        },

        updateText: function (newText) {
            this.$element.text(newText);
        }
    };

    // Create new instances
    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Test(this, options));
        });
    }

    // Init
    $('.d-1').testPlugin({
        elementText: 'First element',
        elementColor: 'red'
    })
    $('.d-2').testPlugin({
        elementText: 'Second element',
        elementColor: 'green'
    })
    $('.d-3').testPlugin({
        elementText: 'Third element',
        elementColor: 'blue'
    })

    $('#textChanger').on('click', function() {
        $('.d-3').testPlugin('updateText', 'Third element updated text')
    })

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-1"></div>
<div class="d-2"></div>
<div class="d-3"></div>
<button id="textChanger">Change text for 3rd element</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin is encapsulated inside the `data` object of the element. In order to access its method, you must call the plugin from the `data` object and then use it.

This line in your code is the reason for encapsulation of the plugin with a plugin-name into the data object of an element on which the plugin was initialized.

`$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Test(this, options));`

Note that your plugin name is `plugin_testPlugin`

```js
(function ($) {

    var pluginName = 'testPlugin';
    var defaults = {
        elementText: 'Default element text',
        elementColor: '#fff'
    };

    function Test (element, options) {
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.$element = $(element);

        if (this[options]) {
            return this[options].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof options === 'object' || !options) {
            return this.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }

    // Main methods
    Test.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            this.$element.text(this.options.elementText);
            this.$element.css('color', this.options.elementColor);
        },

        updateText: function (newText) {
            this.$element.text(newText);
        }
    };

    // Create new instances
    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Test(this, options));
        });
    }

    // Init
    $('.d-1').testPlugin({
        elementText: 'First element',
        elementColor: 'red'
    })
    $('.d-2').testPlugin({
        elementText: 'Second element',
        elementColor: 'green'
    })
    $('.d-3').testPlugin({
        elementText: 'Third element',
        elementColor: 'blue'
    })

    $('#textChanger').on('click', function() {
        var d3 = $('.d-3').data('plugin_testPlugin');
d3.updateText('Hi There Im updated');

    })

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-1"></div>
<div class="d-2"></div>
<div class="d-3"></div>
<button id="textChanger">Change text for 3rd element</button>
```